# Return an out parameter from a variable query

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to build a stored procedure that will convert an ID to a displayable value for any key in a given database. For that purpose, I added a table named LookupMap that specifies which fields to use for KeyField and DisplayField.

```
TableName     KeyField      DisplayField
---------     --------      ------------
Company       CompanyId     CompanyName
Location      LocationId    LocationName
```

I'd like to pass in a table name and a Key value and get back the Display value. The following is what I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[GetLookup]
@TableName varchar(50), 
@Key varchar(50),
@DisplayValue varchar(255) out
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @DisplayField varchar(50)
DECLARE @IdField varchar(50)
Select @DisplayField = DisplayField, @IdField = IdField 
    From LookupMap where TableName = @TableName

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
SET @sql = N'SET @DisplayValue = (SELECT ' + @DisplayField + N' FROM ' + @TableName + 
               N' WHERE ' + @IdField + N' = ''' + @Key + N''')'

Print @sql
Set @DisplayValue = (EXEC (@sql))

END
```

Everything works up to the last line, but I don't know how to get a value back from the dynamic query and assign it to an out parameter.  Also, while I known the keys are unique and there will be only one match, I realize that I'm going to need to so something to assign a table result to a varchar.

And feel free to tell me my approach is all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to set the variable directly through the dynamic SQL, you could create a temp table and use the exec(@sql) for the insert statement.

So

```
    CREATE TABLE #Result (result varchar(50))

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
            SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @DisplayField + N' FROM ' + @TableName + 
                   N' WHERE ' + @IdField + N' = ''' + @Key + N''''

    INSERT INTO #Result
    EXEC(@sql)

    SELECT @DisplayField = result FROM #Result
```